# Socket.io FileNotFoundException in android

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

[image]I try to create socket connection between note.js and android.This is node.js source

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.101.139:8080' );

socket.emit('initialize', { 
    host: "*******",
    entity: "*******"
} );    

socket.on('onconnect', function (data) {
    console.log(data);    
});

socket.on('onerror', function (data) {
    console.log(data);    
});

socket.on('device', function (data) {
    console.log(data);    
});
```

Client Display!
This is android source

```
 try {
        SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("http://192.168.101.139:8080");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                if ("echo back".equals(event) && args.length > 0) {
                    Log.d("SocketIO", "" + args[0]);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                Log.e("onDisconnect","onDisconnect");

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                Log.e("onConnect","onConnect");
            }
        });
        socket.emit("echo", "hello");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When i run my app i have FileNotFoundException.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.bekakukhalashvili.unipaypalyertest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-   core:2.2.2',   {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/socketio.jar')
```

}

[I'm using this socket.io library](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/issues)
In node.js side i'm socket.io latest version  1.7.3
how i can solve my problem and  what would be my problem?

Comment: can you paste the detail error message

Comment: post your gradle , error message as well

Comment: I uploaded log screenshot  @Caspain Caldion

Comment: I updated gradle source  @quick learner

Comment: compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

Comment: try using gradle ,i seen the example and find this, maybe it helps,https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-android-chat/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Comment: that URL, where is it generated from, is it accessible from any computer?

Comment: If you can please tell  problem in my source .I don't need another library @quick learner

Comment: yes.it is  @Caspain Caldion

Comment: First thing, why initialized the socket like that, you have not combined with your server, are you using express?

Comment: What do you mean ? node.js side or android side ? @Caspain Caldion

Comment: node side, what framework you using. The way you are initializing the socket, it seems standalone websites.

Comment: We are using node.js with socket.io @CaspainCaldion

Comment: yea but what framework, express,koa,sails etc

Comment: We are not using any framework on serverside just only socket.io lib

server.listen( 8080 );

io.on('connection') ... @CaspainCaldion

Comment: Sorry @CaspainCaldion server user express

Comment: yea not recommended , make use of node js server architecture,  you see socket.io is like parasite it needs a host to bind to.

Comment: We are using express @CaspainCaldion

Comment: var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138214/discussion-between-baxri-and-caspain-caldion).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach socket.io to node.js instance server. Currently your implementation is standalone,Socket.IO enables real-time event-based communication between one or more clients and a server. It works on every platform, browser or device and is fast and reliable. It's often used in analytics, document collaboration, streaming and instant messaging.

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client) {  
console.log('Client connected...');

client.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});


app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
res.json('txt':'hello')
});

server.listen(your_port);
```

this way a url will be generated , whenever any attempts connection, then socket.io connects as well, then real time communication is then possible.

Comment: what you then need to do is make that url public, so android can connect as well because local host is not possible outside of your address space.

Comment: to overcome this situation either host your application online , eg Heroku is awesome, or use a tunneling software that broadcasts you ip to the internet such a software is ngrok.

Comment: My code is same. we are using local ip (192.168.101.139:9090) address but this devices are same in vlan.

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    var express = require('express');  
    var app = express();  
    var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    var http = require('http');
    var urlencode = require('urlencode');

    io.on('connection', function (socket) {    
     console.log( 'new connection -> ' + socket.id );   
    });

    server.listen( 8080 );

<!-- end snippet -->

Comment: that ip address is the problem, you use port 8080, but your ip port 9090

Comment: this is my source's screenshot.I mistaked when posted code.Now post are same @Caspain Caldion

Comment: this is very strange, question that ip address, what is it not in domain form, are you obfuscating the address?

Comment: What is a different between domains and local IP ? @Caspain Caldion

Comment: before i say anything, is that ip your machine ip, verify with ipconfig?

Comment: if you can please write me in private chat @Caspain Caldion

Comment: there we go, make sense. first thing you on windows or linux?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138215/discussion-between-caspain-caldion-and-baxri).